# Android: Sending SMS works on Emulator but NOT on real devices

Tags: android, android-emulator, sms, device, telephony

**Updated:**
I have tried this code on another phone (4.1.2), it works perfectly. But when I tried on the phone using 4.4.2, it does not work, it returns "Radio Off". My app is set as default app for handling message FYI.

Here is my Activity to send SMS:

```
public class ViewConversation extends Activity {
SQLiteManager sql;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.inbox_conversation);

    init();
    initListView();
    initSendSMS();
}

@Override
public void onBackPressed() {
    startActivity(new Intent(this, MainLayout.class));
}

private void init() {
    sql = new SQLiteManager(this);
}

private void initListView() {
    ViewConversationAdapter adapter = new ViewConversationAdapter(this, getMessages());
    ListView lv = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.lv_conversation);
    lv.setAdapter(adapter);
}

private String[] getMessages() {
    Bundle b = getIntent().getExtras();
    String fk_conversation_info = b.getString("fk_conversation_info");
    sql.open();
    String[] result = sql.getConversationSMSs(fk_conversation_info);
    sql.close();
    return result;
}

/* ---------- SEND SMS PART ---------- */
private void initSendSMS() {
    final EditText et_phone = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.et_addPhoneNum);
    final EditText et_message = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.et_messageBody);

    Button bt_send = (Button) findViewById(R.id.bt_send);

    bt_send.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            String phoneNumber = et_phone.getText().toString();
            String message = et_message.getText().toString();

            sendSms(phoneNumber, message);
        }
    });
}
private void sendSms(String phoneNumber, String message) {
    String SENT = "SMS_SENT";
    String DELIVERED = "SMS_DELIVERED";

    PendingIntent sentPI = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(this, 0,
            new Intent(SENT), PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT);

    PendingIntent deliveredPI = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(this, 0,
            new Intent(DELIVERED), PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT);

    //---when the SMS has been sent---
    registerReceiver(new BroadcastReceiver(){
        @Override
        public void onReceive(Context arg0, Intent arg1) {
            switch (getResultCode())
            {
                case Activity.RESULT_OK:
                    Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(), "SMS sent",
                            Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                    break;
                case SmsManager.RESULT_ERROR_GENERIC_FAILURE:
                    Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(), "Generic failure",
                            Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                    break;
                case SmsManager.RESULT_ERROR_NO_SERVICE:
                    Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(), "No service",
                            Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                    break;
                case SmsManager.RESULT_ERROR_NULL_PDU:
                    Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(), "Null PDU",
                            Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                    break;
                case SmsManager.RESULT_ERROR_RADIO_OFF:
                    Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(), "Radio off",
                            Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                    break;
            }

            ViewConversation.this.unregisterReceiver(this);
        }
    }, new IntentFilter(SENT));

    //---when the SMS has been delivered---
    registerReceiver(new BroadcastReceiver(){
        @Override
        public void onReceive(Context arg0, Intent arg1) {
            switch (getResultCode())
            {
                case Activity.RESULT_OK:
                    Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(), "SMS delivered",
                            Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                    break;
                case Activity.RESULT_CANCELED:
                    Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(), "SMS not delivered",
                            Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                    break;
            }
        }
    }, new IntentFilter(DELIVERED));

    SmsManager sms = SmsManager.getDefault();
    sms.sendTextMessage(phoneNumber, null, message, sentPI, deliveredPI);
}
}
```

Here is my manifest for this Activity:

```
 <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
package="vn.hak_developers.spamsms" >

<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_SMS" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_SMS" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.SEND_SMS" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.RECEIVE_SMS" />

<application
    android:allowBackup="true"
    android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
    android:label="@string/app_name"
    android:theme="@style/AppTheme" >
    <activity
        android:name=".MainLayout"
        android:label="@string/app_name">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>

    <activity
        android:name=".setting.SettingMethods"
        android:label="@string/app_name" >
    </activity>

    <activity
        android:name=".viewsms.ViewBanSim"
        android:label="@string/app_name" >
    </activity>

    <activity
        android:name=".viewsms.ViewNhaDat"
        android:label="@string/app_name" >
    </activity>

    <activity
        android:name=".viewsms.ViewNganHang"
        android:label="@string/app_name" >
    </activity>

    <activity
        android:name=".viewsms.ViewThongBao"
        android:label="@string/app_name" >
    </activity>

    <activity
        android:name=".viewsms.ViewNhaHang"
        android:label="@string/app_name" >
    </activity>

    <activity
        android:name=".viewsms.ViewThuRac"
        android:label="@string/app_name" >
    </activity>

    <activity
        android:name=".viewsms.ViewConversation"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:windowSoftInputMode="adjustResize">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.SEND" />
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.SENDTO" />
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.BROWSABLE" />
            <data android:scheme="sms" />
            <data android:scheme="smsto" />
            <data android:scheme="mms" />
            <data android:scheme="mmsto" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>

    <!-- BroadcastReceiver that listens for incoming SMS messages -->
    <receiver android:name=".smsmanager.SmsReceiver"
        android:permission="android.permission.BROADCAST_SMS">
        <intent-filter android:priority="1000">
            <action android:name="android.provider.Telephony.SMS_DELIVER" />
            <action android:name="android.provider.Telephony.SMS_RECEIVER" />
        </intent-filter>
    </receiver>

    <!-- BroadcastReceiver that listens for incoming MMS messages -->
    <receiver android:name=".smsmanager.MmsReceiver"
        android:permission="android.permission.BROADCAST_WAP_PUSH">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.provider.Telephony.WAP_PUSH_DELIVER" />
            <data android:mimeType="application/vnd.wap.mms-message" />
        </intent-filter>
    </receiver>

    <!-- Service that delivers messages from the phone "quick response" -->
    <service android:name=".smsmanager.HeadlessSmsSendService"
        android:permission="android.permission.SEND_RESPOND_VIA_MESSAGE"
        android:exported="true" >
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.RESPOND_VIA_MESSAGE"/>
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
            <data android:scheme="sms" />
            <data android:scheme="smsto" />
            <data android:scheme="mms" />
            <data android:scheme="mmsto" />
        </intent-filter>
    </service>
</application>

</manifest>
```

It works perfectly when I send SMS between emulators, but when I run the app on my phone, it toasts Radio Off (my phone is not in airplane mode).

Please advise.

Comment: You need to setup the correct permissions in your AndroidManifest.xml

Comment: Hi EJTH, I have just added my manifest code. Please review, thanks.

Answer (score 0):

I made an app that sent SMS last year, but I did not sent the intent in the method.
I did it like this:

```
sms.sendTextMessage(Number, null, message, null, null);
```

Try this, maybe it works.

**EDIT**

There's no need to use all the code in `sendSMS(String phoneNumber, String nessage)`

simply do this:

```
private void sendSMS(String phoneNumber, String message)
{
     //PendingIntent pi = PendingIntent.getActivity(this, 0,
     //   new Intent(this, ViewConversation.class), 0);

     SmsManager sms = SmsManager.getDefault(); 
     sms.sendTextMessage(phoneNumber, null, message, null, null);//edited
     Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(), "SMS sent", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
}
```

the `PendingIntent` object (pi) is simply pointing to the same activity (ViewConversation.java), so when the SMS is sent, nothing will happen.

Hope this helps.

Comment: Hi Ashkan, thanks for your help. I tried your code but it didn't work either!

Comment: I tried your code and it crashed:

java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to resume activity {vn.hak_developers.spamsms/vn.hak_developers.spamsms.viewsms.ViewConversation}: java.lang.NullPointerException

Comment: Can you please post the whole error. And also, try to remove the pendingIntent part. See the edit.

Answer (score 0):

i fixed, you cant send if sim in SIM 2...I set sim send, call in SIM 1 is working.